# Scala wait for async call to complete in loop

Tags: scala, asynchronous, foreach, future

I am new to scala and I have to make an async call ( Elastic indexing using elastic4s ) while iterating through a for each loop. What is the best way to do that in scala.

```
val data = List("1","2","3","4")

data.foreach(element=>{
          asyncCall(element)
        })
```

How to do some action after all the asyncCall is completed. I don'nt want to do anything with the response. Just print success if everything success and print fail if any of the call fails. asyncCall returns Future[T].

Comment: Are you intending to du all the asyncCalls in parallel or one after the other?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Future.sequence`. It changes `List[Future[T]]` to `Future[List[T]]`.

So in your example:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

val f = Future.sequence(data.map(asyncCall)) // Future[List[String]] 

//you can now do something when future finishes:
f.onComplete{
  case Success(s) => println(s"Evethings fine: $s")
  case Failure(e) => println(s"Something went wrong: $e")
}
```